# Error when install to google play

Tags: java, android, apk

I tried to fix my problem, but couldn't. My problem is error shown when set to google play. Please help me, I cannot resolve the errors.

```
06-17 11:58:04.855 29388-29388/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
06-17 11:58:04.865 172-172/? E/BufferQueueCore: [Starting kz.pillowz.app] setDefaultMaxBufferCount: setting count to 3, previous is 2 
06-17 11:58:04.956 29388-29388/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: kz.pillowz.app, PID: 29388
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application kz.pillowz.app.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kz.pillowz.app.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kz.pillowz.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kz.pillowz.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:661)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6027)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1805)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kz.pillowz.app.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kz.pillowz.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kz.pillowz.app-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1003)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:651)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6027) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1805) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kz.pillowz.app.App
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 13 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
06-17 11:58:04.986 753-29404/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
```

Comment: What are the exact steps that caused this error?